# Elysia cron module does not execute cron job automatically

Tags: 7, cron

I have installed the elysia cron module and setup the cron job. My module has a cron function `test_cron()` which inserts some data into a table.

This function lists in the elysia cron status page. I have setup the the default scheduled rule to `*/1 * * * *` to run the cron after every minute.

When I click on the **run** infront of the `test_cron()` the cron runs and some data inserts into the database.

But this the manual method, I want to execute the cron after every minute therefore I defined the scheduled time for the `test_cron()`,  but it does not executed automatically after every minute.

What should I do? Is there any other configuration which I should do to run the cron automatically?

Comment: Elysia cron cannot control the time at which cron runs it can only schedule it. You need to make sure that crontab in your apache server is set to run every minute.

Comment: Where is the crontab located so that I can set it to run my cron function after every minute.

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/23714 I have used crontab linux command, not sure of any other way to set it up.

Comment: if we have to setup the crontab to run cron on specified time then what is the reason the elysia cron module displays the rules of a cron function?

Answer (score 6):

As I mentioned before *Elysia Cron can only schedule the cron jobs not control it* when to run.
If system crontabs are set to run every minute elysia cron module can control it from there on.
Check out the [drupal page](http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) for that module.

> [Elysia Cron](http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron)
>   However to get the full potential out of elysia cron and have the full
>   control over you tasks a further step is needed: you need to configure
>   the system crontab to execute drupal cron every minute.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Elysia Cron does not change your server's crontab settings and cannot, all it does is skips some cron tasks on each cron job if they are set to run *less* frequently than the current crontab setup.