# How do I run multiple cron jobs?

Tags: 7, cron

I want to run 4 cron jobs inside Drupal, in four different times.

How can I achieve that? Is there any module for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try out the [Ultimate Cron](http://drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron) module.

> Runs cron jobs individually in parallel using configurable rules, pool management and load balancing. Multiple rules per cron job. Configuration per job (enable/disable, rules, etc.)

There is also the [Elysia Cron](http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) module.

> Elysia Cron extends Drupal standard cron, allowing a fine grain control over each task and several ways to add custom cron jobs to your site.

Comment: @Lasitha Note that to allow Elysia cron to initiate Cron Jobs at four different times, you need to have crontab scheduled for every minute. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/37929/790

Answer (score 3):

[Elysia Cron](http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) is the module you are looking for.

> Elysia Cron extends Drupal standard cron, allowing a fine grain control over each task and several ways to add custom cron jobs to your site.